# Почему скрипт может не работать в IE 9-11?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка

Во всех браузерах,кроме ИЕ9-11 скрипт отрабатывает, и ширина обертки становится равной ширине изображения. А в ИЕ этого не происходит.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var img = document.querySelectorAll('.item__img');
  var wrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.item__img-wr');
  var makeEqualWidth = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < wrapper.length; i++) {
      wrapper[i].style.width = img[i].offsetWidth + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.items {
  margin: 35px 0 35px 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  &__item {
    width: 175px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    float: left;
    &:hover {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
      box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px red;
      border-color: red;
    }
  }
}

.item__img-wr {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #999;
}

.item__img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 92px;
  height: 102px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #555;
  &_small {
    width: 60px;
    height: 70px;
  }
}

.item__signature-wr {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="items clearfix">
  <div class="items__item">
    <div class="item__img-wr">
      <img src="http://credittoolz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/free.png" alt="" class="item__img">
    </div>
    <div class="item__signature-wr">
      <div class="item__signature">подпись<br> к изображению в три строки</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items__item">
    <div class="item__img-wr">
      <img src="http://credittoolz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/free.png" alt="" class="item__img item__img_small">
    </div>
    <div class="item__signature-wr">
      <div class="item__signature">подпись<br> в две строки</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items__item">
    <div class="item__img-wr">
      <img src="http://credittoolz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/free.png" alt="" class="item__img">
    </div>
    <div class="item__signature-wr">
      <div class="item__signature">подпись</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items__item">
    <div class="item__img-wr">
      <img src="http://credittoolz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/free.png" alt="" class="item__img">
    </div>
    <div class="item__signature-wr">
      <div class="item__signature">подпись</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items__item">
    <div class="item__img-wr">
      <img src="http://credittoolz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/free.png" alt="" class="item__img">
    </div>
    <div class="item__signature-wr">
      <div class="item__signature">подпись</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="items__item">
    <div class="item__img-wr">
      <img src="http://credittoolz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/free.png" alt="" class="item__img">
    </div>
    <div class="item__signature-wr">
      <div class="item__signature">подпись</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: возможно проблема которая обсуждается тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171247/ie9-equivalent-of-queryselectorall

Comment: А фото у тебя тоже по этой же ссылке подключены или в папке с проектом находятся? Если да, скачай эти же фото себе локально  подключи...

Comment: @Air простите, как и куда я могу подключить локально картинки со своего проекта? Да и нужно ли это, если таманалогичные простые картинки сейчас подключены, просто им заданы разные размеры. Суть в том,что мне надо заставить обертку картинки принять ширину ребенка, а не растягиваться по ширине родителя. И чтобы это работало в ИЕ9

Comment: Ну их надо скачать, к себе...  И в места `src="http://credittoolz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/free.png"` прописать так `src="и тут прописать путь к папке в которой эти фото сохранены/free.png"`

Comment: @Air если вы о том, что в проекте они должны лежать локально в папке,то естественно,так и есть))) Эти фотографии я подключил исключительно для примера здесь.Но они по пропорциям и размерам такие же, как и те,что я в проекте использую

Comment: )))))))? ну я об этом тебя спрашивал...  ты хотя бы укажи в вопросе, какую ошибку выдает.

Comment: @Air в том то и дело,что в консоле никаких ошибок не выдает...просто в ИЕ9 не работает.Везде работает,а в ИЕ9 - нет. Вру,в ИЕ10-11 тож не работает

Comment: Странно. Потерпи,  может кто из более опытных ответит...  Я не вижу в чем может быть дело

Comment: @Air ага, в любом случае,спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста......

Comment: Пожалуйста, добваьте в вопрос - что значит, что скрипт не работает? Не надо отвечать в комментариях, отредактируйте вопрос кнопкой "Править".